# Как реализовать автоматическое обновление сайта (не перезагрузка)?

Tags: php, cms, логика, обновления

Пишу свой *велосипед* (CMS), и не могу придумать как реализовать правильно автообновление ядра. (новая версия).

Пока идея такая:

- Грузить Архив (обновление)
- Доставать новые фалы
- Бекапить старые
- Заменять

Но чувствую, что-то тут не так...

Comment: Если zero downtime - не ваш конек, сфокусируйте усилия на том, что умеете делать лучше и чем сильна именно ваша CMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автодеплой - довольно деликатная тема, где нет сформировавшихся стандартов, но есть идеи, считающиеся обязательными к исполнению, и набор сформировавшихся практик. К сожалению или к счастью, все это влияет на архитектуру.

#### Обновление базы данных

Обновление базы данных должно происходить через миграции. Правильно написанные миграции позволят откатиться в случае появления каких-либо проблем, и не оставить БД в подвешенном состоянии посередине приложенного обновления. Если вы не используете никакого фреймворка, то я рекомендую [phinx](https://phinx.org/) для использования. Кроме того, они внесут дополнительный вклад в независимость от конкретного движка БД.

Миграции действительно являются самой распространенной из упомянутых здесь практик - это почти стандарт в индустрии.

#### Бэкап

Все, что может быть потеряно - это пользовательские файлы, конфиги и БД. БД на всякий случай стоит сбрасывать на диск, по крайней мере, пока нет серьезного опыта с миграциями, а с пользовательскими файлами все еще хитрее: они просто должны лежать снаружи приложения, и тогда обновление не будет их захлестывать. С конфигами аналогично - хранить в `.yml` снаружи движка, в случае, если придется их обновлять - писать аналогичный движок миграций, чтобы не потереть чьи-то настройки.

#### Zero-downtime

Это самое вкусное слово в этом посте. Это будет немного сложно реализовать при использовании composer, но все возможно.

Суть примерно такая: код нового приложения разворачивается в отдельной папке, затем применяются миграции, после которых приложение способно работать как со старым, так и с новым кодом, затем папка с кодом приложения атомарно подменяется (т.е. для ОС не существует момента, когда папки не существует или когда в ней смешанное содержимое), затем добиваются миграции, которые нужны для этого обновления. Поддерживать эту систему - самое сложное, но **приложение вообще не останавливается ни на секунду**. Никаких режимов обновления, никаких "подождите" - пользователь даже не понимает, что его обновили. Это очень тесно соприкасается с приложениями, которые деплоят по многу раз на дню, и, скорее всего, вы никогда не видели гитхаб в дауне, хотя там за день может десяток обновлений прийти.

Атомарно это делается, как правило, через симлинк (ноду на ФС, которая при попытке доступа пересылает на другую ноду, если грубо - ярлык). В тот момент, когда необходимо заменить версию на более свежую, симлинк подменяется на свежий симлинк с другим target. При этом код этого симлинка вообще не видит - когда он выполняется, он исполняет обычные файлы по их реальному адресу, и работа приложения, по факту ведется внутри реальной папки, на которую указывает симлинк. Даже после подмены сорцов симлинков он продолжит использовать старые адреса, поэтому запросы доработают, как им и положено.

*Возможно, я таки смогу дописать целиком все, что хочу, но позже*

Answer (score 0):

За некоторым уточнением — извлекать новые файлы лучше в отдельный каталог — вполне разумные шаги.

И про бэкап базы данных (если используется) забывать не стоит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, спасибо, постараюсь! у меня встречная огромная просьба: не изменяйте, пожалуйста, регистр букв при редактировании *моих* ответов. заранее спасибо!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin При исправлении сообщений любой пользователь имеет полное право нарушать ваши странные предпочтения во имя правил русского языка.

Comment: @Discord, не имею ничего против такого права. особенно если за мной сохраняется право вернуть изменения регистра букв (и только их) «назад».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin У вас есть право откатить. У модератора есть право счесть это вандализмом и надругательством над великим и могучим.

Comment: @Discord, логично. именно потому (чтоб не прослыть вандалом) я и попросил модератора (после исправления им нескольких моих ответов именно с целью замены регистра букв) не вносить таких правок. надеюсь, попросил достаточно вежливо и с глубоким уважением к чужому мнению.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Если что, я упёртый козёл (по меньшей мере бородой), баран (по меньшей мере одним рогом) и грамматический нацист, меня просьбами не пронять.

Comment: @Discord, у каждого свои недостатки (улыбка). / хотя ваше стремление сделать окружающий мир лучше я готов приветствовать обеими руками, но всё же останусь при своём мнении относительно употребления букв верхнего регистра в *написанном мною* тексте. / не могу похвастаться своей фанатичностью в этом вопросе: ну, исправил кто-то *мой* ответ, так исправил, и специально возвращать *только* регистр букв я, конечно, не стану. / но если мне потребуется дополнить или исправить *ошибки* в *своём* ответе, то, конечно, исправлю и регистр. в общем, ни возражать, ни конфронтировать, — не собираюсь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вы б хоть объяснили позицию. Ну, "леньставитьпробелы", "нинавижу руский языг", "лень жать шифт я имба скоропечаталка всем завидовать запятые для неудачников", "чИтАтЕлИ мОеГо ТеКсТа УрОдЫ и ДоЛжНы СтРаДаТь", "у меня шифт сломался" в конце концов...

Comment: @Discord, спасибо за участие! попробую объяснить. / с моей скромной точки зрения, текст, в котором часто изменяется размер шрифта, выглядит неэстетично. даже если это всего два размера. / а заглавная буква — это [буква, которая увеличена в размерах по сравнению со строчной (и часто обладает другой графемой)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Заглавные_буквы). / в написанных мною текстах я стараюсь употреблять (по возможности) буквы **одного размера**. / позиция эта выработалась давно, но навязывать её кому-либо у меня нет ни желания, ни права, ни возможности.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Мне страшно даже представить ваши страдания при написании текста на английском языке, в том числе кода. Там же неэстетичные палки во все стороны! Да что там, даже цифры в большинстве шрифтов неправильной высоты. И почему вы ставите наклонные черты? Они же выше остальных символов, всю красоту портят.

Comment: @Discord, а ещё **жирные** буквы такие жирные, а *наклонные* такие наклонные… (улыбка). я ж не эстетствующий фанатик, и не персонаж из анекдота, которого не устраивало, что одно яйцо ниже другого. / там, где это *действительно* необходимо, например, при написании документации (и ещё в «миллионе» случаев), я запросто употребляю заглавные буквы. / но везде, где это возможно, предпочитаю использовать шрифт одного размера.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд лучше выполнять обновление в следующей последовательности:

- загружаем обновление
- блокируем изменение данных на сайте (по сути переводим его в режим обслуживания)
- бэкапим базу данных
- определяем какие файлы подлежат изменения, бэкапим их
- обновляем файлы
- обновляем структуру БД
- запускаем скрипт обновления (при необходимости)
- чистим кэши
- выводим сайт из режима обслуживания